# Function to convert seconds in a "0h 0min 0s" format in PHP

Tags: php, function, time

- I couldn't find it here, so I'm creating this question and sharing to help someone else that needs it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function timeConversion($totalSeconds) {
        $interval = (new DateTime())->diff((new DateTime())->add(new DateInterval("PT${totalSeconds}S")));
        return $interval->format("%hh %imin %ss");
}
```

Comment: Oh well, living and learning that there is always a fastest way. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need less than 24 hours, then:

```
$totalSeconds = 12345;

$dt = new DateTime('@' . $totalSeconds);
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! But I would rather have the possibility to have days also.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find it here, so I'm sharing to help someone else that needs it!

```
function timeConversion($totalSeconds) {

  $minutesInAnHour = 60;
  $secondsInAMinute = 60;
  $secondsInAnHour = 3600;

  $seconds = $totalSeconds%$secondsInAMinute;
  $hours = (int)($totalSeconds/$secondsInAnHour);
  $totalMinutes = $totalSeconds - $seconds;
  $minutes = ($totalMinutes-$hours*$secondsInAnHour)/$minutesInAnHour;

  return $hours . "h " . $minutes . "min " . $seconds . "s";

}
```